# purrr map to each item in list not just list

Tags: r, purrr

I have a `round` function that I would like to apply to each element in each list, but my code currently rounds the entire list. How can I fix this using `purrr`

```
> library(purrr)
> library(tidy verse)
> 1:3 %>%
      map(~ rnorm(104, .x)) %>% 
      map(~ round(max(.x, 0), 0))

 [[1]]
[1] 4

[[2]]
[1] 5

[[3]]
[1] 6
```

If it helps, a non-purrr way of doing this would be the following

```
a = sapply(rnorm(104, mean = 20, sd = 10), function(x) round(max(x, 0), 0))
b = sapply(rnorm(104, mean = 20, sd = 10), function(x) round(max(x, 0), 0))
c = sapply(rnorm(104, mean = 20, sd = 10), function(x) round(max(x, 0), 0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in one `map` inside another. The way you were calling `max` was giving the max of all the numbers in that vector, with 0 tacked onto the end of the vector, so it only gives a single value.

Try this instead: use `map_dbl` to map over every value in the vector, take the max of *just* that single value and 0, then pass it along to `round`.

```
1:3 %>%
    map(~rnorm(104, .x) %>% map_dbl(max, 0) %>% round())
```

Answer (score 1):

@camille Answered this question well. This is an alternative using `pmax` in a custom function

```
positive_round <- function(...) round(pmax(..., 0), 0)

1:3 %>%
  map(~ rnorm(104, .x)) %>% 
  map(~positive_round(0,.x))
```

Comment: Nice, `positive_round` seems like a handy function to reuse